# Elastic metricbeat total system file descriptors

Tags: elasticsearch, metricbeat

I am trying to get total number of file descriptors in the system.
According to this resource:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/metricbeat/current/exported-fields-system.html#_fd

There is a field available to use:

> system.process.fd.open

This shows the file descriptors per process.

**Question:** Is there any way to get all (total/sum) the file descriptors/handles for the system regardless of process? Total number of file descriptors for all the processes.

Please help.

Thanks.